# Tag synonym suggestions

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, tagging

I don't know if there should be a single thread for proposed tag synonyms, but I'll go ahead and leave this relatively generic in case that's desirable (and assuming there's not already a thread for this I've missed).

One issue that might be controversial is the fact that "common use" and technical meaning may not by identical.   This could be a problem when using or misusing tags like homophones, homonyms, look-alikes, and homographs.

(I see that much of this has been discussed in [Tags and technical terms](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/tags-and-technical-terms) ).

Are users expected to correctly tag these?  Should there be a single catch-all (or catch-many) category?  Or should corrections be up to other users, possibly leaving these changed and/or corrected without comment?

Anyway, here are a couple that look like they should be merged or synonymized:

[spelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) <--> [orthography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography)
[meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) <--> [semantics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantics)

Comment: I'm actually voting to close this question. A generic "tag duplicates" question is too broad -- I suggest that you post a separate question for the specific tag suggestions that you have.

Answer (score 2):

*Orthography* means "the conventional spelling system of a language." *Spelling* generally refers to how a word is written.

I think that most of the questions tagged with [orthography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) should be really tagged with [spelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling), if they are not questions about the conventional spelling systen of English.

[semantics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantics) seems more abstract than [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning). If I would have to choose between the two, I would opt for [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning).

Comment: I don't have any problem with any of these options, but I would like to see them merged.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not excited about either of these categories, but I can see their utility:

[esl](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esl)
[learning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning)

I would recommend merging those.   I think ESL is more appropriate, but I don't know if it is better or worse as a tag for those who need it.  'Learning' is too general, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

"Semantics" is the linguistic field that deals with the meanings (of words, phrases, sentences). As we are *not* talking *about* linguistic semantics as a science here on this site, it is actually used in the same place as "meaning" and not as something more abstract. I think that [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) should be kept and [semantics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantics) should be a synonym.

If this site featured discussions about the meaning of words and also about semantics as a science, then it would be a valid tag. I think tags should generally indicate what a question is *about*.

Therefore, I would also vote to keep [spelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) as a tag and [orthography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) as one of its synonyms.